# How would a Low Fantasy Iron Age setting be effected if Inbreeding and Divination were directly connected?

Tags: society, magic, politics, religion, genetics

I'm trying to make a world with a very low fantasy setting in it. The world itself is currently at levels or similar to that of the Classical Civilizations during the later parts of the Iron Age i.e. think 1st or 2nd century AD.

There are five major empires across the world, dozens of smaller kingdoms and hundreds of micro or city states. The five major empires have all existed for at least a hundred years now so they're pretty well established. Civilization in this world has lasted for over eleven thousand years though most people only know their history from a century prior. Even the most established scholars, academics and "knowledge" class workers have an accurate understanding of what happened in the past 1200 years.

So overall its basically like our Late stage Iron Age world with all that it entails except for one difference. Divination and Inbreeding are interconnected.

Basically this means that people have to be inbred to actually get this power. Not just for one generation but at least a couple of generations with a consanguinity of two or closer. They are not immune to the effects of inbreeding and suffer similar to it as regular humans do though. As a result most such "clans" or "family units" don't last longer than ten generations if that.

Even so this divination only allows for a future sight of up to a day plus the number of inbred generations. It's far sight is also the number of generations times ten for the amount of senses and understanding. The frequency of these visions is also relevant to the amount of generations. Each individual clan can not bred with each other and thus just insular. Furthermore their rituals to get their visions are unique to themselves and each clan a completely different ritual. The rituals require some sort of tool, device or set up to be used which only is given once to the "first seer" of the family by the "gods". If the ritual is ever lost or forgotten or erased from written word it is lost forever.

To Give you an idea:

> Person 1 is a seer who was born from a third generation of a mountain clan that practices this horrific stuff. The mountain clan gets by raiding foreigners, taxing "locals" of the empires and promising their powers to the Empire e.g. the local equivalent of Roman Empire, in times of war. They have done so for generations
>
> Person 1 has thus become their tribute to the battles against a revolt that is about to start in the south. As a result they take themselves, their partner and a few slaves with them to meet with the General. Over the course of the next two years of campaigning the person will be able to accurately predict/see anything in the next four days, up to thrice a day, and with regards to 600 meters of their person (3*20*10). This allows them to accurately predict how certain battles may go over the course and the campaign is victorious.
>
> To see into the future, Person 1 must carefully butcher a calf or similar juvenile mammal. They then look into the entails of the mammal and watches how its blood drains out of it whilst chanting a family rhyme/story/legend which lets them see into the next four days. Once done they have said vision of the future.
>
> However this does not mean that Person 1 is not without genetic problems. Furthermore due to the messed up family situation they are not the best adjusted persons at all.

Nevertheless whilst my story will have such a seer, which follows similar rules to Midsummar, they are just one of five perspectives, with about 10 chapters given to them out of the 40 chapters.

**Situation Around the Wars**

Think of the current character currently living in a situation similar to that of the Roman Empire. There's several revolts or campaigns going around so the upper classes marginally supports or at least tolerates this inbreeding. Due to the size of the empire e.g. 35 million people there are 14,000 of such seers in clans but ones like Person 1 are of a very "pure" stock and only make up a tenth of such seers.

Due to their usefulness in wars, trade, planning and agriculture every village or town leader has at least one or a bond with a clan, in their employ.

**Other Useful Notes**

People in this world do not know why divination or magic works like it does here. They just know it does here. Records or legends of the first seer go back two thousand years but as I said before people only have a clear understanding of what happened in the past thousand years at best. Furthermore this a very violent world filled with slavery, war, class conflict, religious issues and other things of "classical" civilizations.

It is an interconnected world nonetheless as such a group of people allow for captain, who is willing to pay, to travel quicker and safer (e.g. a trip takes 10% less longer when one is aboard on average and there's much fewer problems onboard or when onshore). People do and tend to travel somewhat more than regular classical/iron age people but even then that's the equivalent of twice their regular distances.

This divination-inbreeding is a constant throughout the world and has been. Many states and leaders acknowledge this and in exchange they also fight against religions or people who tend to wish the death of such "seers" simply because of how useful it is.

**Altogether I thus have a few questions**

How would it be seen?

How would people or religion change to this?

How would they fit into wider society?

What would be considered their roles?

Comment: 1. '...follows similar rules to Midsummar' – what does this mean?
2. You've asked multiple open-ended and opinion-based questions.

Comment: (1) "Effected" and "affected" are different words with different meanings; "effected" means "done" and "affected" means "changed". (2) If you really mean how the setting would be "effected", then the answer is that it would be effected by the author imagining it then sitting down and writing it. (3) If you mean how it would be affected, then you must explain how it was before this strange linkage appeared (so that we know what is the baseline state), and it what way it developed (so that we can consider the side-effects).

Comment: This is your plot. You seem to have a grasp of the problems of both divination and inbreeding. Why are you asking anything here? It's pure opinion.

Answer (score 1):

### The Prophets of Doom:

The even bigger question is how divination affects an iron-age culture. The inbreeding should really be a secondary question. I'll try to touch on both. The actual advantage of seeing locally a few days into the future might be less than it seems, especially if knowing means you have fixed events you can't change. Battles would naturally be a key use, but even here the outcomes could be really difficult to figure out, especially if rival seers are at odds.

Religiously and economically, the inbred are clearly blessed, and for any family of common folk, there would be a strong incentive to inbreed so as to obtain magic. Faiths discouraging inbreeding would be at a significant disadvantage compared to those that permitted it, and I'm sure some would encourage it (although the long-term side effects suggest establishing a class system where those inside are supported by society, but not in charge of making decisions). Since this is a long-term project to have an inbred family, a state or religion might carefully regulate and monitor who they DO or DON'T allow to inbreed. Too many results in consequences for population genetics AND uppity peasants, too few and you don't get the benefits of prophesy.

It depends on if the visions can affect the outcomes of events or not. Knowing you'll lose a battle might mean you can't avoid it, and can only alter the things you don't know. Or, you could have two seers constantly changing their prophesies based on what the other guy learns from HIS prophet, and predictability completely breaks down.

I see a serious issue if the seer is only able to see what happens within 600m of themselves. There's a strong incentive for armies without seers themselves to be dodgy and evasive, making sure battles don't happen at predictable places. There would also be a pressure to move away from set-point battles to an attrition/asymmetric model where numerous small, hard to predict engagements happen. You need to either have messengers report to thin air in places you know your prophet was days ago (to give them accurate info due to limited range) or you need to move your prophets around a lot so they can see the environs you want them to predict in. One version is a "tell" so your enemies know where to avoid battles or historically significant events. The other means your shifty seers can be targeted for attack by rival shifty seers who guide ever-changing assassination plans to take out the other guy's seers.

The limited range and communication system also means you can plant false messages by getting seers bad info. Just because a messenger was somewhere in two days telling you the battle was lost doesn't mean the battle was really lost. misinformation and conscious manipulation of events could be a real tool in a general's arsenal. A general might fully plan to do one thing, but have a complicated plan of alternatives based on outcomes, predictions, or dice-rolls (depending on how the power works) to make the future a blurry mess.

Prophetic visions would seriously alter the economics of disasters. Fires stop, as each one is damped out before it happens OR a house is evacuated of goods and people before the fire. Murder is really strange - you may have knowledge of an unavoidable murder before it happens, and a person who had no plans to kill someone may be reviled, then forced into killing another to fulfill prophecy. OR unscrupulous seers may accuse persons of murder, who are then locked up on the seer's say-so with no recourse to evidence. Given all that inbreeding, mental stability might be a real issue, and people could question a Cassandra (who was doomed to see the future and not be believed).

Cold-killing (assassination) of seers would be big business, ***IF*** you can do it (if you can't change fate). The limited number of full-on seers makes taking out rival seers very valuable. Once the rival seers are dead, the family line is wiped out, and it will be generations before a people will have seers again. Once again, it is important for the church and state to control the seers, both for their protection, but also so they can get rid of unreliable seers on demand (being locked in a tower for a longer period than your vision-length means that, like Cassandra, you can know of your upcoming death and do nothing to change it).